# How to jar files in maven whose directory structure is not similar to sourceDirectory?

Tags: maven

I have written a pom.xml to compile java files which are in the directory "D:\Windchill_Market\ERP Connector\SourceCode\Build\src1\src\main\java\com\sample".

Now I have to jar all the files which are in the directory "D:\Windchill_Market\ERP Connector\SourceCode\Build\src1".

Below in my pom.xml:

```xml
<sourceDirectory>D:\Windchill_Market\ERP Connector\SourceCode\Build\src1\src\main\java</sourceDirectory>
<plugins>  
    <plugin>                    
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>             
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>              
        <version>2.5.1</version>              

    </plugin>   
    <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>attach-sources</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

I am able to generate class files . But I am not able to jar all files from my required directory. Only files from sourceDirectory is getting jarred. I tried using include tag in maven-source-plugin. But its not working.

Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks for all the answers. I was able to solve this problem using build-helper-maven-plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Maven uses different folders for source and other files (so called ressources). From `src\main\java` it compiles all `.java` files and packages the resulting `.class` files into the jar. All other files in that directory are getting ignored to my knowledge.

Now if you want other files to be packaged too, put them in `src\main\resources` instead.

**EDIT**

To manually specify a resource directory add

```
<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>D:\Windchill_Market\ERP Connector\SourceCode\Build\src1\src\main\resource</directory>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

to your `<build>` section

Comment: Ya i tried that. But since the <sourceDirectory>D:\Windchill_Market\ERP Connector\SourceCode\Build\src1\src\main\java</sourceDirectory> is till src\main\java i am not able to jar the contents which are in src\main\resources. I am specifying the sourceDirectory till src/main/java because sonar wants the entire package structure to generate the results of the compiled class files

Comment: Never specify an absolute path in <sourceDirectory>. Actually, remove that since src/main/java is default.

Comment: In fact, never use absolute paths anywhere in your POM, e.g. for the resources as mentioned in this answer above.

Comment: @rec Yes, I should have mentioned that. Works only if the pom is in the  projects root of course. In OPs case `D:\Windchill_Market\ERP Connector\SourceCode\Build\src1`

Answer (score 0):

The maven-source-plugin does exactly what it should. It jars up the sources in src/main/java. It may include src/main/resources too, not sure.

If you manage somehow to make it archive everthing starting from the root of your project, you abuse it. For Maven to properly use the resulting JAR, its inner structure must reflect that of the normal JAR - so all the packages must be there, just the files inside are ".java" instead of ".class". If that is not the case, Eclipse or other tools will not find these source files.

If you want to create what you might call a "source distribution" of your project, you should have a look at the [Maven Assembly Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/). It allows to you create a package from your project in a very flexible way. It would require a way longer answer through to walk you through the process. Better read the documentation on the plugin and come back when you have more specific issues. There is a [pre-defined configuration](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/descriptor-refs.html#src) which may work for your case.

In brief, something like this should work:

```
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <configuration>
      <descriptorRefs>
        <descriptorRef>src</descriptorRef>
      </descriptorRefs>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

This Maven feature was mortal for JavaFX project. Run in Eclipse - all works fine. Make jar - get 'javafx jar java.lang.IllegalStateException: Location is not set' on start.
Solution: put your resource files (fxml, png etc.) to folders inside source package (here src/MyProjectName/javafx), then change pom file:

```
<sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
<resources>
  <resource>
    <!-- initially Maven makes this string <directory>src</directory> -->
    <directory>MyProjectName/javafx</directory>
    <excludes>
      <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
    </excludes>
  </resource>
</resources>
```